# Can someone explain the file ~/.config/uGet/CategoryList.xml

Tags: uget

I would like to understand the file `~/.config/uGet/CategoryList.xml`

```
<?xml version='2.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<UgCategoryList version=''>
  <category>
    <name value='Home'/>
    <ActiveLimit value='3'/>
    <FinishedLimit value='300'/>
    <RecycledLimit value='300'/>
    <DownloadDefault>
      <DataList>
        <DataClass name='common'>
          <folder value='/home/linux'/>
          <ConnectTimeout value='30'/>
          <TransmitTimeout value='30'/>
          <RetryDelay value='6'/>
          <RetryLimit value='99'/>
          <MaxConnections value='1'/>
          <MaxUploadSpeed value='0'/>
          <MaxDownloadSpeed value='0'/>
          <RetrieveTimestamp value='1'/>
        </DataClass>
        <DataClass name='relation'>
          <hints value='0'/>
          <AttachedStamp value='0'/>
          <MessageType value='0'/>
        </DataClass>
      </DataList>
    </DownloadDefault>
    <DownloadIndices/>
  </category>
</UgCategoryList>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the XML file for uGet Categories.

---

```
<name value='Home'/>
```

self-explanatory

---

```
<ActiveLimit value='3'/>
```

The total number of active downloads allowed at one time inside this category.

---

```
<FinishedLimit value='300'/>
<RecycledLimit value='300'/>
```

Limit of Downloads to keep in the history of downloads. Finished is completed downloads and Recycled is downloads that have been "soft deleted".

---

```
      <folder value='/home/linux'/>
```

The default folder of this category.

---

```
      <ConnectTimeout value='30'/>
      <TransmitTimeout value='30'/>
```

The timeouts in seconds before a connection is retried.

---

```
      <RetryDelay value='6'/>
      <RetryLimit value='99'/>
```

Delay is how many seconds it will wait before trying a connection. Limit is how many times it will retry in total before the download errors out.

---

```
      <MaxConnections value='1'/>
      <MaxUploadSpeed value='0'/>
      <MaxDownloadSpeed value='0'/>
```

Maximum Number of Connections per download . . . this can be limited by a server so not always possible.

Maximum Upload Speed is based on your connection and what you want to limit it at. 0 = Unlimited.

Maximum Download Speed is basically the same except downloading. 0 = Unlimited.

---

The rest you are very unlikely to modify so you probably not really need to know what it does. I can clarify if needed though.